# Ways to automatically insert a space after a LaTeX command (inserted by an AucTeX shortcut, e.g. `g) if the next keystroke is a letter

Tags: latex, auctex

With AucTeX, one can insert many LaTeX commands using shortcuts.

For example in a math environment (e.g., between $ $), the shortcut `` `g `` insert `\gamma`. Normally right after `\gamma` if I would like to type a letter I should make a space, for example `$\gamma a=1$`, but if I would like to type a number, a symbol or another latex command, it is not necessary, for example `$\gamma\alpha=1$` or `$\gamma*1=\gamma$ or $\gamma1=\gamma$`, or `$\gamma^1=\gamma$`.

Is there a way in AucTeX to insert a space right after a latex command (inserted by an AucTeX shortcut, e.g. `` `g ``) if the next keystroke is a letter?

I think this can significantly increase the speed of typing, because the space should be inserted anyway.

I have added the requirement *inserted by an AucTeX shortcut* to avoid the complicated situations like `\leq` and `\leqslant`.

Comment: Here is a rough idea for a solution: Put a function on `post-self-insert-hook`. The function should examine `last-command`, and if it is whatever auctex uses to expand shortcuts, it should examine the character just inserted and optionally insert a space in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
  (defun my-insert-space-if-alnum (orig-func &rest args)
    "Insert an extra space if the char read is alphabetical or a number."
    (let ((c (read-char)))
      (when (memq (get-char-code-property c 'general-category) '(Ll Lu Nd))
        (insert ?\ ))
      (insert c)))
  (dolist (f '(
               LaTeX-math-alpha
               LaTeX-math-beta
               LaTeX-math-delta
               LaTeX-math-Delta
               LaTeX-math-epsilon
               LaTeX-math-phi
               LaTeX-math-Phi
               LaTeX-math-gamma
               LaTeX-math-Gamma
               LaTeX-math-eta
               LaTeX-math-theta
               LaTeX-math-Theta
               LaTeX-math-kappa
               LaTeX-math-lambda
               LaTeX-math-Lambda
               LaTeX-math-mu
               LaTeX-math-nu
               LaTeX-math-nabla
               LaTeX-math-pi
               LaTeX-math-Pi
               LaTeX-math-chi
               LaTeX-math-rho
               LaTeX-math-sigma
               LaTeX-math-Sigma
               LaTeX-math-tau
               LaTeX-math-upsilon
               LaTeX-math-Upsilon
               LaTeX-math-omega
               LaTeX-math-Omega
               LaTeX-math-xi
               LaTeX-math-Xi
               LaTeX-math-psi
               LaTeX-math-Psi
               LaTeX-math-zeta
               ))
  (advice-add f :after #'my-insert-space-if-alnum))
```

Comment: This  works well for the commands in the list,  would be nice if it would be possible to detect the command manually in order to not miss something like like `\rightarrow`. But this is a very good step toward a complete solution.